# simple linear search program that is not giving desired output

Tags: python

```
def linear_search():
  a= raw_input("ënter the list")
  a = a.split()
  a_len = len(a)
  num = int(input("ënter the no to be searched "))
  for i in range(a_len):
    if a[i]== num:
      print("no found")
    else:`enter code here`
      print("no not found")
linear_search()
```

This program is giving o/p as for eg if a = ['12','13','16'] and num = 16 
than
it return o/p as 
no not found
no not found 
no not found 
 please find the error in program , i am using 2.7 version of python

Comment: 16 is not equal to '16'. Convert your list of strings to list of ints.

Answer (score 1):

16 is not equal to '16'.

```
>>> 16 == '16'
False
```

Convert your list of strings to list of ints. You can iterate through the elements of the list and convert them to `int` individually. Like this:

```
a = raw_input("ënter the list")
list_a = [int(i) for i in a.split()]
```

Or you could use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) after inputting the list from the user with:

```
a = raw_input("ënter the list")
list_a = map(int, a.split())
```

Comment: Equivalently (and arguably more pythonically), you can use a list comprehension: `list_a = [int(i) for i in a.split()]`.

Comment: And you can collapse it even further by doing this: ``found = num in (int(i) for i in a.split())``, if you don't actually care *where* the item is found, just that it is. This saves the creation of the second list, and will short-circuit converting the values after the number is found.